PrimeNG component's appearance differs when running in local environment
I was testing to check the look and feel of PrimeNG components (v17.18.11).
Followed the installation steps and then ran the app locally to check the UI components.
Taking an example of table component, below is the screenshot from the PrimeNG docs: 
And here's the screenshot of my local app implementing the table: 
I can see that there's a slight look difference in between both (probably the fonts). And this is with all other components also.
I have already added the core and theme styles in angular.json file:
"styles": [
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ]

Can anyone kindly explain why is this happening? Do I need to set something else here?
Thanks.

looks like the same font to me.  What's the difference you are seeing?

ah, wait I see a difference in the "6" and the "a"... that is a different font or font-face.  It could be due to different installed fonts on the platforms/OSes.  You might just double-check doing a Ctrl-F5 in the browser to be sure it's not a local cache issue.  Otherwise you have to be sure a web font is being downloaded.  (not real sure what happens if an existing, same-name font file is already found)

I think that's "Inter Var" fontface... and you're showing Google's version of that font: https://fonts.google.com/variablefonts?vfquery=Inter  Might check this thread: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/10909
